# How to initialize YouTubeService in F#?

Tags: c#, f#, youtube

I'm new to F# and I don't have any C# experience (I have Java but I don't think it's relevant in this case). I'm trying to write a simple F# code that accesses Youtube playlist data. Youtube Data API provides an example in C# but I can't wrap my around to convert it to F#.

How one would write below BaseClient.Initializer in F#?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

```cs
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat tricky as a beginner, since the sample uses C# object initialization syntax. F# has a different syntax where properties that get initialized are done in the constructor call. Here's an equivalent bit of code (written more how I'd do it, rather than the Google sample):

```
use youtubeService =
    let initializer =
        BaseClientService.Initializer(
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "some-name")
    new YouTubeService(initializer)
```

Note that the `new` is actually needed to avoid a warning right now, since `YouTubeService` is a disposable.